# Android Firebase get List Data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am trying to get movies list info in my application.

**MainActivity**

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseMovies= database.child("Movies");

        DatabaseReference databaseReference=databaseMovies;
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    SingleItem singleItem=postSnapshot.getValue(SingleItem.class);
                    items.add(singleItem);
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,items.get(0).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

**SingleItem**

```
public class SingleItem {

    private String image;
    private String link;
    private String title;
    private String views;

    public SingleItem(String image, String link, String title, String views) {
        this.image = image;
        this.link = link;
        this.title = title;
        this.views = views;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getViews() {
        return views;
    }
}
```

Application crashes, The object class I made don't read the info right.
I want to store a list of movie object and each object contains the movie info.

[image]

Comment: can you mention what exception you are getting?

Comment: added it, you can check it now

Comment: Hi , please add setter's, only getter's  are there , if not required remove constructor.

Comment: The error says it all you are missing a constructor in your singleton class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the **`public no-argument constructor`** need for Firebase in your `SingleItem` class. Remember, when the Firebase Realtime Database SDK deserializes objects coming from the database, it requires that any objects in use to have a `public no-argument constructor` that it can use to instantiate the object. Fields in the objects are set by using the `public setter` methods or direct access to public members.

If you don't use `public no-argument constructor`, the SDK doesn't really know how to create an instance of it. In fact, most serialization libraries will have the same requirement.

Your class should look like this:

```
public class SingleItem {

    @PropertyName("Image")
    private String image;
    @PropertyName("Link")
    private String link;
    @PropertyName("Title")
    private String title;
    @PropertyName("Views")
    private String views;

    public SingleItem() {} //no-argument constructor

    public SingleItem(String image, String link, String title, String views) {
        this.image = image;
        this.link = link;
        this.title = title;
        this.views = views;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getViews() {
        return views;
    }
}
```

See also the added annotations. I have added this annotations because of the difference between your fields from your model class which contains first letter lowercase and the actual key from the database which contains first letter uppercase.

To ge the data from your database, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference moviesRef = rootRef.child("movies");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String Image = ds.child("Image").getValue(String.class);
            String Link = ds.child("Link").getValue(String.class);
            String Title = ds.child("Title").getValue(String.class);
            int Views = ds.child("Image").getValue(Integer.class);
            Log.d("TAG", Image + "/" + Link + "/" + Title + "/" + Views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
moviesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: could you provide me an example of the constructor?

Comment: The initial issue for which you have posted the questions was solved. A quick way to get the data is as in my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

`public no-argument constructor` means that you need a constructor with no passing data in it

```
public SingleItem() {
    // in order to avoid null values, init your data
    this.image = "";
    this.link = "";
    this.title = "";
    this.views = "";
}
```

Also, i see in your list of data from `firebase` data that your key is first letter uppercase. In this case, you should use `@PropertyName` annotation. Ex:

```
@PropertyName("Image")
public String image;

@PropertyName("Link")
public String link;

//etc
```

Since you have private variables, you can annotate methods and have private variables:

```
@PropertyName("Image")
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

From documatation, you can annotate private variables also, but for me is not working. You can try it.

Comment: it still gives me an error on this line
SingleItem singleItem=postSnapshot.getValue(SingleItem.class);

Answer (score 0):

The error console says it all `You are missing a no argument constructor`.

You may want to use [Json2Schema](http://jsonschema2pojo.org) to make the work much more easier. As you haven't added the serializable elements to your class which might cause you trouble later on. ex: When you want to serialize the class you have to implement `Serializable` also `SerializeName` & `Expose` annotation [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Thus change your `Singleton` class to this

```
public class SingleItem implements Serializable{

@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("views")
@Expose
private String views;

//NO ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR
SingleItem(){}

public SingleItem(String image, String link, String title, String views) {
    this.image = image;
    this.link = link;
    this.title = title;
    this.views = views;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getViews() {
    return views;
}
}
```